Is there an ecosystem crate that provides a bloom filter implementation?
I would like to use a bloom filter in my program. Is there an existing crate I can use that will let me do this?

There is this rust crate:
https://github.com/jedisct1/rust-bloom-filter
Maybe that one works for you. Or are you looking for a program example that uses bloom filter?

You can probably easily modify the bloom filter used by the Solana validator to work on-chain: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/bloom
It looks like the atomics might be an issue, and some rand functions can be removed.
